# Don't show me questions in the review queue that I have already flagged before

Tags: support, bug, review

Reviewing a filtered close votes queue.

The first few questions load super fast as they were recently asked but once I get past the last few days and the questions shown are like 3 months old it [takes ages to load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201997/the-deeper-you-dig-the-longer-you-wait).

The problem I am actually directing here is that even though I don't mind waiting the extra few seconds (til that's fixed) I don't necessarily want to be shown a question that I have already flagged before.

It seems like [this problem has been raised before and has a status-completed on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142439/received-a-question-in-the-close-vote-review-queue-that-i-had-already-voted-to-c?lq=1), but I can see the bug came back to re-raising the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Posts that I flagged as “off-topic” should not appear in my review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202551/posts-that-i-flagged-as-off-topic-should-not-appear-in-my-review-queue)? (Assuming you correctly said "flagged" as opposed to "voted on")

Comment: @Dukeling not really a duplicate. I am reporting a bug on a topic that has a status completed.

Comment: If you meant "flagged", the issue you linked to is not the same (at least not as far as I can tell, because it refers to "voted on"). And the issue you linked to is more than a year old, while the possible duplicate is a month old, why can't it be a duplicate?

Comment: I have the same issue. Recently gained the right to review close votes, all the old questions I flagged previously appear in the review queue. Especially annoying if you spend some minutes in reading the question before you realise it's totally useless.